# how to use mocking in unit testing in scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, unit-testing, easymock

hi i am new in Unit Testing and i want to test it using mock objects .i want to test whether data is successfully stored in mongoDB or not 
here is my code

```
package models.RegularUserModels
import models.UserModels.UserStatus._
// User will give information to Signup  

    class DirectUser() extends RegularUser{
      override val uuid = "direct123"
       override val firstName ="sara"
       lastName = "waheed"
       email = "user@example.com"
       secondryEmail  =Some("user2@example.com") 

        userStatus =ACTIVE

     }
```

And here is the class which i want to test

```
package models.RegularUserModels

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.QueryBuilder

class directUserStore {
  def write(directuser:DirectUser) ={
    val serverAddress=new ServerAddress("Localhost",27017)
    val client= MongoClient(serverAddress)

   val CourseDB = client("arteciatedb")//get database Name
    val collection = CourseDB("directUser")//get collection Name

    collection.drop()

        collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("_id",directuser.uuid)
                        .append("Email",directuser.email)
                        .append("SecondryEmail",directuser.secondryEmail)
                        .append("FirstName",directuser.firstName)
                        .append("LastName",directuser.lastName)
                        .append("UserStatus",directuser.userStatus.toString())
                        )

  }

}
```

make an scala object to check code is working correctlly

```
object Test extends App{

val directUser= new DirectUser() 

/////////////////////////DirectUser mongo DB//////////////////////////
//insert in mongoDB
val directUserStore= new directUserStore
directUserStore.write(directUser)
}
```

Now i want to perform test on DirectUserStore.scala class ,So in src/test diectory of sbt i created this class

```
package testingModels.RegularUserModels
import models._
import models.RegularUserModels._
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest.MustMatchers._
import org.scalatest.Spec
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.easymock.EasyMock._
import org.scalatest.mock.EasyMockSugar

class DirectUserStoreTest extends FunSpec with org.scalatest.MustMatchers with EasyMockSugar {
    describe("A DirectUserStoreTest"){
      it("should use easy mock to mock out the DAO classes")
      {
        val DirectUserMock= createMock(classOf[directUserStore])
       /* val directUserStore= new directUserStore
        //replay, more like rewind
        replay(DirectUserMock)
        //make the call
        directUserStore.write(DirectUserMock)
        //verify that the calls expected were made
         verify(DirectUserMock)
*/      val directUser = new DirectUser 

        expecting{
        DirectUserMock.write(directUser)  
        }
        whenExecuting(DirectUserMock) {
        val directUserStore= new directUserStore
        directUserStore.write(directUser)

          }
      }
    }
}
```

but when i type test in sbt my test failed

```
[info] DirectUserStoreTest:
[info] A DirectUserStoreTest
[info] - should use easy mock to mock out the DAO classes *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
[info] directUserStore.write(models.RegularUserModels.DirectUser@1fe2433b)
[info] Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
[info]   at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.replay(MocksControl.java:173)
[info]   at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:2074)
[info]   at org.scalatest.mock.EasyMockSugar$$anonfun$whenExecuting$2.apply(EasyMockSugar.scala:421)
[info]   at org.scalatest.mock.EasyMockSugar$$anonfun$whenExecuting$2.apply(EasyMockSugar.scala:420)
[info]   at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
[info]   at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
[info]   at org.scalatest.mock.EasyMockSugar$class.whenExecuting(EasyMockSugar.scala:420)
[info]   at testingModels.RegularUserModels.DirectUserStoreTest.whenExecuting(DirectUserStoreTest.scala:11)
[info]   at testingModels.RegularUserModels.DirectUserStoreTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(DirectUserStoreTest.scala:28)
[info]   at testingModels.RegularUserModels.DirectUserStoreTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(DirectUserStoreTest.scala:14)
[info]   ...
[info] Run completed in 2 seconds, 50 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
```

please guide me how can i achieve my goal . i know i am doing some big mistake but i need guidance hence its the first test i am writing in my life 
help please

Comment: For such persistence layer testing, I think that's important to make clear what you want to check. With current mock, you can test that the user is passed as argument, which I'm not sure is really valuable.

Comment: i want to test whether data is inserted in mongoDB or not ..the values i am inserting is same

Comment: `val DirectUserMock= createMock(classOf[directUserStore])` how are you trying to test `directUserStore` if you create a mock of it? You seem confused about what mocks actually are. You use a mock of `Foo` to test an object `Bar` that has a dependency on `Foo`.  If you want to test actual insertion into MongoDB you don't want to mock, you want to test your actual code.

Comment: As vptheron said, if you want to testing that data are present in your MongoDB after you `write`, than it will be integration testing and require a test DB (and possibly fixtures to setup it). What could be valuable to me is to test that your persistence layer is calling appropriately the Mongo driver according argument your function: checking that the persistence layer is performing the appropriate conversion from custom model BSON and call driver insert as expected. Checking that after an insert on a Mongo collection, data are present in this collection is quite testing the MongoDB engine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you going to be Mongo client developer? Otherwise there is no point in testing if the value get stored in the DB in Unit Tests (you can do this in Intergration test, but I don't see a point anyway).
Think for example of portability - unit tests assuming existence of MongoDB on default address will fail on any other computer without a MongoDB installed.
Secondly - You have to assume some things are working - and hence that assumption that MongoDB API works as it should - is a valid assumption. Otherwise you can question everything (is string concatenation working or not? Why trust one library over another?) - I guess you see my point

What you should actually test is whether you pass the correct values to the Mongo API. This can be done by mocking.
You can use [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) while I prefer to use [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) as it works well with Scala and have more functionality available. No problems with combining those two if you need.

Your class `directUserStore` has unreplacable dependecies to some classes that can't be changes and therefore easily mocked - for example `serverAddress` and `client` - they can be moved to class level ones.
Then, you can override them with a mock (generated for example by Mockito), which will return another mock of `collection` and verify, if the correct methods were called on that collection.

Comment: can you please explain that via code please pleaseeee

Comment: ...or you can skip mocking altogether. Scala has enough facilities (nice traits for instance) that you can often build better code with no need to mock, nor to deal with the intrinsic complexity of mocking libraries (not trivial). This is just my humble opinion, but I've seen this argument many times before.

Comment: I disagree with you on this; verifying you pass the correct details to the mongo API only verifies you use the API as you think you should, not that you've done it correctly.  When working with data stores the only way to know you've done it correctly is to actually do it.  You're right about making assumptions about ports etc. so this should be controlled as much as possible through the test or build system itself, e.g. bringing up mongo, docker/vagrant etc.

Comment: You are speaking about integration tests, that's where setting up mongo etc is appropriate. The question was about unit testing, and I do think that unit tests should be as independent as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want mocking at this level of code. Your directUserStore class is responsible for interacting with MongoDb, storing and retrieving data. Mocking out MongoDb will only tell you that you've interacted with the Mongo API in the way that you think you should, not necessarily the right way.

What you should do here is spin up a MongoDb instance and round-trip your data. If you only care that the data can be stored and read, just write it/read it back and verify it. If you really care about how it's stored (hint: you probably don't) then you will have to poke MongoDb manually in the tests.