# How to test MongoDB working properly Using ScalaTest or Mocking

Tags: mongodb, scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalatest

Hi i am new in unit testing i want to test whether data is successfully stored in mongoDB or not abd my code is working properlly as i am new need help in testing how to test my `DirectUserStore.scala` class either using scalatest and mocking please help me, Here is my code

```
package models.RegularUserModels
import models.UserModels.UserStatus._
// User will give information to Signup  

    class DirectUser() extends RegularUser{
      override val uuid = "direct123"
       override val firstName ="sara"
       lastName = "waheed"
       email = "user@example.com"
       secondryEmail  =Some("user2@example.com") 

        userStatus =ACTIVE

     }
```

And here is the class which i want to test

```
package models.RegularUserModels

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.QueryBuilder

class directUserStore {
  def write(directuser:DirectUser) ={
    val serverAddress=new ServerAddress("Localhost",27017)
    val client= MongoClient(serverAddress)

   val CourseDB = client("arteciatedb")//get database Name
    val collection = CourseDB("directUser")//get collection Name

    collection.drop()

        collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("_id",directuser.uuid)
                        .append("Email",directuser.email)
                        .append("SecondryEmail",directuser.secondryEmail)
                        .append("FirstName",directuser.firstName)
                        .append("LastName",directuser.lastName)
                        .append("UserStatus",directuser.userStatus.toString())
                        )

  }

}
```

please guide me i will be very thankfull to you 
make an scala object to print inserted values on console

```
object Test extends App{

val directUser= new DirectUser() 

/////////////////////////DirectUser mongo DB//////////////////////////
//insert in mongoDB
val directUserStore= new directUserStore
directUserStore.write(directUser)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use mocking in unit testing in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538614/how-to-use-mocking-in-unit-testing-in-scala)

Comment: You don't want to unit test the database. You want to unittest *your* logic. DB connections and such are tested during integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want mocking at this level of code.  Your `directUserStore` class is responsible for interacting with MongoDb, storing and retrieving data.  Mocking out MongoDb will only tell you that you've interacted with the Mongo API in *the way that you think you should*, not necessarily the right way.

What you should do here is spin up a MongoDb instance and round-trip your data.  If you only care that the data can be stored and read, just write it/read it back and verify it.  If you really care about *how* it's stored (hint: you probably don't) then you will have to poke MongoDb manually in the tests.